# Set Safari 7 dv tools console to clear on reload?

Tags: macos, safari, web-inspector

I use Safari 7.03 for web development.

One thing I noticed is that the console log doesn't re-set on a reload of the page.  You need to clear it manually.

So if you run a page with a JS error, it shows, then you fix the error in your JS code and reload the page and the error is still in the log -- but it's from the LAST time.

Chrome clears the error log every time.  Is this a setting in Safari somewhere?

Comment: yes, this is annoying. Especially when the little clear console trashcan has chosen to disappear.

Comment: this same in safari 9.1

Answer (score 3):

Either inline in your HTML, or in an external Javascript file. 
Call the function `console.clear();`

Now, every time you go to reload your page, the console will be cleared.

Comment: This does not work in Safari. Apparently a bug?